# Rsync not deleting

Tags: linux, centos, synchronization, rsync, mirror

I have setup rsync to mirror a directory from a source server(a) to a mirror(b). I have gotten it to send new files that are on the source but when I delete a file from the source it doesn't end up deleting it.

Below is what I use to call rsync:

```
rsync -vhzrplt --stats --delete --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -q'  --exclude="core/" --exclude="cache/" /home/(a)/public_html (b):/home/(b)/public_html/
```

When I run rsync i get the output below:

```
stdin: is not a tty
sending incremental file list
public_html/
deleting public_html/test.html

Number of files: 389
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 3.16M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 9.25K
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 9.33K
Total bytes received: 47

sent 9.33K bytes  received 47 bytes  1.25K bytes/sec
total size is 3.16M  speedup is 336.81
```

As you can see it shows that it's deleting test.html but it never ends up doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using this instead:

```
rsync -vhzrplt --stats --delete --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -q'  --exclude="core/" --exclude="cache/" /home/(a)/public_html/ (b):/home/(b)/public_html/
```

Add trailing slashes to paths that are folders.

Comment: Is the trailing `/` in `/home/(a)/public_html/` the change that solved this issue?

Comment: Everything worked when I put trailing "/" after directory names (in exclude, destination and source directory names).

Answer (score 1):

rsync has tons of options -- see `man rsync`

e.g.:

```
--del                   an alias for --delete-during
--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
--delete-before         receiver deletes before transfer (default)
--delete-during         receiver deletes during xfer, not before
--delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
--delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not before
--delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

It's really recommended to read that man page thoroughly because there are so many useful options.